# Vision Framework Animal Detection

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vision

I am trying to run the demo code from this doc. The camera is just black.
I know it is recent but anyone had the same problem?

The download Sample is below.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_animal_body_poses_with_vision

I tried basic steps.
Such as adding camera permission.
Changing the info.plist.

Comment: Are you running on a device?

Comment: Yes, on Ipad 10th generation.
I also update all the devices.